# Reordering EKReminders

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, eventkit

The EventKit framework provides methods which fetch an array of reminders/events for a given search predicate.

What I'm trying to figure out is the best way of reordering a `UITableView` with cells representing `EKReminders`. Besides reordering the table itself, what's the best way to handle remembering the order of the table?

I thought about storing an array in `NSUserDefaults` containing indexes corresponding to indexes of another array which contained the reminders. Then, you could rearrange the first array and then ask the second array for the reminder at the stored index.

I also considered storing pointers to `EKReminder` pointers in a similar manner, but that seemed useless given that the pointers would eventually be nil when the program ended, and if the pointers to pointers where stored, they'd no longer point to the same thing upon relaunch.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reorder EKReminder in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153843/reorder-ekreminder-in-a-list)